# How do I save and delete my 2 Text files with Realm?

Tags: swift, xcode, tableview, realm

How do I save and delete my 2 Text files with Realm?

Following is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource , UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var text1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var text2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var ttableview: UITableView!

    //delete row and tableview and array
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            array1.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            array2.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            ttableview.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return array1.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = ttableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! Cell
        cell.lable1.text = array1[indexPath.row]
        cell.lable2.text = array2[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    var array1 = [String]()
    var array2 = [String]()
}
```

I want to save and delete my 2 text fields in the table view.

[image]

Below is the code to add it to tableview

```
@IBAction func Add(_ sender: Any) {
    array1.insert(text1.text!, at: 0)
    array2.insert(text2.text!, at: 0)
    self.ttableview.reloadData()
}

func queryPeople(){
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let allPeople = realm.objects(CCat.self)
    for person in allPeople {
        print("\(person.name) to \(person.job)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Please mention what are the issues you are facing in this code and also add some description.

Comment: how to use realm here i want to save data in delete i want to code you can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read Realm's documentation first.
https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/

To save object to Realm, define model class as subclass of `Object`.

```
class Person: Object {
    // Optional string property, defaulting to nil
    dynamic var name: String? = nil

    // Optional int property, defaulting to nil
    // RealmOptional properties should always be declared with `let`,
    // as assigning to them directly will not work as desired
    let age = RealmOptional<Int>()
}
```

Then create an instance of the model class.

```
let author = Person()
author.name = "David Foster Wallace"
```

Create instance of `Realm`.

```
// Get the default Realm
let realm = try! Realm()
// You only need to do this once (per thread)
```

Begin a transaction and add the object to the Realm.

```
// Add to the Realm inside a transaction
try! realm.write {
  realm.add(author)
}
```